# Vehicle json or api for javascript

Tags: reactjs, api, package

does anyone know an api or package which are lists all cars by 2019 and any brands and models. I want to use it for a project what list a component with all cars models and brands.

Comment: You can (and should) just google such an API; StackOverflow isn't the place for API suggestions.

Comment: This is what I found on Google: [Vehicle API](https://edmundsapi-preprod.github.io/api-documentation/vehicle/)

Comment: I found this api but it has not been maintained for 6 years...
I have been searching for a while and I can't find anything that is up to date and written in javascript or in json format and to be free. @user1538301

Answer (score 1):

Quick google search found these:

> https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/
>
> https://www.carqueryapi.com/

If you're not sure how to make api calls in React, I would refer you to this page in the docs:

> https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: It seems some models and brans are missing and I can't find another.
Example 'Dacia' models are missing @Andrew Mellor